# Computed function being called twice in vuejs app

Tags: vuejs2

I'm learning some VueJS by implementing a simple shopping cart.

Here's my HTML:

```
<div id="app">
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Product</th>
        <th>Unit price</th>
        <th>Quantity</th>
        <th>Total</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr v-for="(cartItem, index) in order.cartItems">
        <td>{{ cartItem.productName }}</td>
        <td>{{ cartItem.unitPrice }}</td>
        <td>{{ cartItem.quantity }}</td>
        <td>{{ lineTotal[index] }}</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="shipping">
        <td>Shipping</td>
        <td>{{ shipping }}</td>
        <td>{{ totalItems }}</td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tfoot>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="3">TOTAL</td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
    </tfoot>
  </table>
</div>
```

Here's the JS:

```
const shipping = 1.5;

const app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    shipping: shipping.toFixed(2),
    order: []
  },
  created() {
    fetch('https://api.myjson.com/bins/1fk6ua')
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(json => {
      this.order = json.order
    })
  },
  computed: {
    lineTotal: function () {
      return this.order.cartItems.map(function (cartItem) {
        return (cartItem.unitPrice * cartItem.quantity).toFixed(2);
      });
    },
    totalItems: function(){
      return this.order.cartItems.reduce(function (totalItems, cartItem) {
        return totalItems + parseInt(cartItem.quantity);
      }, 0);
    }
  }
});
```

Here's a Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/8fg70ud2/.

As you can see I'm only part way through the implementation. I've got the product line totals working by implementing a `computed` function called `lineTotal`. Now I'm trying to get the shipping line working by first getting the number of products in the cart (which will ultimately be multiplied by the `shipping` constant). I've got as far as implementing a `totalItems` function which seems to do the job, but I notice there's now a console error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'reduce' of undefined
```

Digging a bit deeper, it seems that the `totalItems` function is being called twice; the first time `this.order.cartItems` is `undefined` hence the `reduce` call is erroring.

Why is this happening?  I may well be going about all of this in the wrong way so am open to suggestions as to how to move forward; I'm at the very start of the learning curve :)

Thanks.

Comment: You better use https://vuejs.org/v2/api/index.html#beforeCreate rather than #created lifecycle-method. Read carefully how and when create method fires and why you receive error.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When the Vue instance is created, it has a property `order` which you initialized to `[]`. In your `v-for` you try to get `order.cartItems` which also results in `undefined` but you don't notice any problem there, because Vue bails out from creating the structure inside `v-if` never hitting your another computed property `lineTotal`.

But, `totalItems` is computed right away. With `order` still an `[]`. `order.cartItems` is `undefined`. Which obviously does not have `reduce` method. Hence, the error.

Then, in the `created` callback, you actually fetch the data and populate the `order` property with the actual object. Since `order` property is the dependency of the computed property `totalItems` and it has updated, Vue will compute the property again and this time `order` property has the correct data structure. And, things will go fine in the second run.

The solution is quite simple. Wait until your `order` property is populated by using `v-if="order.cartItems"` in the containing `tr` element with the class `.shipping`.